# Drag and Drop from ListView to Explorer

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop, objectlistview

My goal is to able to drag an item from a ListView to Explorer. The way I'm trying to accomplish this is somewhat different though. From searching Google and around this site, I couldn't really find anything that would help me or pertained closely enough to what I'm trying to do. I can barely comprehend some of the examples because I don't understand enough about these drag and drop operations.

Specifically, the control that I'm trying to drag items from is a `TreeListView` from the `ObjectListView` library. The control is populated with nodes that represent the structure inside a archive-like compressed file. Entries are parsed into two different objects representing a file and a directory. Both of these models inherit an interface. When extracting these files normally, I use a `Form` that I instantiate with a collection of nodes and the target path that they will be extracted to as the parameters. It then takes care of extraction. This is so that I can show the overall and singular progress of each file.

Subscribing to the `ItemDrag` event, I know that I need to call `DoDragDrop`. When doing this, I need to be able to instantiate the extraction form only after the drop (when the user releases the mouse) into `Explorer`, and also be able to retrieve the path in which the items were dragged.

For some reason, this seems a lot more complicated than it should be. Any sort of advice or suggestions would be very helpful.

Comment: You can't force the drop recipient's behavior unless it is your app.  The receiving app will interpret the drop in whatever fashion it wishes.

Comment: Not trying to force the drop recipient's behavior.

Comment: You won't see the drop, only the receiving app will, so you can't make a form pop-up when that happens.  Only the receiving app can do that.

Comment: I get what you're saying but I'm not really trying to "see the drop". I just want to be able to extract the files to a temporary directory so the DoDragDrop method can do its thing. I though maybe I could override something in DataObject that would allow me to show the dialog so that the files can extract, and _then_ give it the paths so it can handle the rest. The problem is that I don't know how or even if there's a way to do that by showing the form and extracting the files only _after_ the mouse is released.

Comment: The point is, you won't know when (or if) the mouse is released.  When you start the drag and drop flow, the system takes over and when the mouse is released the system sends that event as a drop on the receiving app, that's why you have no control after the drag leaves your app.

Comment: Also, if you are dropping on Explorer, you won't need to handle the target path in your popup, as Explorer will determine that based on where you drop.

Comment: I know, I was just hoping there was some possible way to accomplish what I'm trying to do no matter what it is. I mean, I've seen WinRAR do pretty much exactly what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what format Explorer expects in the drag object, but this process might work for you.

- When you begin the drag, pre-extract the selected files to some temp
  directory
- Build a DataObject which contains the paths of the files you have extracted in the format expected by Explorer
- Use your DataObject in the DoDragDrop call
- When the user drops on Explorer, the files should get copied from the temp directory to the drop target
- Track all of your extracted files and cleanup when the application exists (id desired)

Hope this helps.

Edit (after some research):

I believe if you use

```
new DataObject(DataFormats.FileDrop, files)
```

where files is a string[] of the filenames to be copied (the ones you put in the temp directory), you shouold have the correct DataObject for implementation.

Haven't had a chance to write a prototype yet to test.  Good Luck!